# Spark List Itemrenderer focus defaults the currentState

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe, state, itemrenderer

I am using a spark list control with an itemrenderer. Whenever I set an itemrenderer's currentState, the moment I mouse out of the itemrenderer, it gets reset to its default state. How can I make an itemrenderer keep its currentState unless I explicitly tell it to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the getCurrentRendererState method on your renderer and returning whatever state you like, including your custom state.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I find it funny that returning currentState in the getCurrentRendererState method fixes the issue. Shouldn't that already be the case? Seems like a better option than returning null by default. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: This is a great point, I have filed a minor enhancement for it here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29061. Please vote for that issue and/or leave a comment with your use case if you would like to see it fixed.